Is there some way to get the effect of LOW_PRIORITY for select in MySQL?
I read mysql document and find for insert there is a LOW_PRIORITY switch while for select there is a HIGH_PRIORITY.
I need a "LOW_PRIORITY" (so to speak) for some of my slow query. For example, there is some like leading wildcard query my customer wants, just like this question in DBA SO, How to perform FullText search on numeric column in MySQL to meet user requirements, to query numeric field in search form '%334%'.
In my case, it is a column with 11 numeric characters for my customers' mobile number and one of my customers has a use case for query 4 digit numbers in the middle.
I initially thought to use FTS, but as the answer there said "When searching for a numeric string in the middle, FULLTEXT is the wrong approach. LIKE is the only approach, and it requires a full scan of the plates. Live with it."
So I have to live with the slow query and also let my customers know that if you do that the result is slow. But I need to make sure that query won't use all my MySQL server's resource so my other customers can do their "normal" query in the meaning time.
As the following slow query log shows, when that customer did his like %xxxx% (the blue bar), the cpu usage (yellow line) increased dramatically.

So I need an effect of LOW_PRIORITY for the leading wildcard like query. Is there a way to do that ?

See if "NGram" search will help. It was added in 5.7.6 for Chinese, but may work well for your app.

How slow is it? To my knowledge, a LIKE condition is not specifically slow. Or you have millions of records? Maybe adding an index on that column would help?

@RickJames I need to search for numeric characters, the column is for numeric characters only (normally 11 digits) and you said in that DBA SO question FTS is the wrong approach. So does NGram help ?

@A.L yes I have millions of record and in my case as it is like %xxxx%, the leading wildcard, so index won't help. My goal is to not let this query uses up all my mysql resource.

In your example, an NGram search would look for rows with '33' and '34', likely to be a good subset.  An Ngram with N=3 would search for '334' via an inverted index a la FULLTEXT, but based on consecutive characters, not words.

MySQL has no feature like you describe.
The options for LOW_PRIORITY and HIGH_PRIORITY apply only to table-locking storage engines like MyISAM or MEMORY. These options have no effect for InnoDB tables. InnoDB is the default storage engine, and the benefits of InnoDB usually outweigh the option to use MyISAM, so you should prefer InnoDB over MyISAM.
Even for MyISAM, the LOW_PRIORITY option isn't available for SELECT queries. That's only for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.
For your scenario, a popular solution is to create a replica database server, and run long-running queries like reports on the replica. This eliminates the potential that the query competes for resource and hinders other important queries on the source server.
Replication in MySQL is asynchronous, which means even if you slow down the replica server a lot with a costly query, it won't have any effect on the source server. It may delay replication a little bit, but that doesn't affect the source.
Another solution in recent versions of MySQL is to add an index for an expression on the substring. Once you create that index, if your SELECT query uses the same expression, it will make use of the index.
mysql> ALTER TABLE mytable
    -> ADD INDEX ((SUBSTRING(mycolumn, 4, 8)));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> explain SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE SUBSTRING(mycolumn, 4, 8) = '3344';
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type | possible_keys    | key              | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | NULL       | ref  | functional_index | functional_index | 35      | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+

The disadvantage of this index is that the position of the substring is fixed in the definition of the index. If the customer changes their mind tomorrow and wants a substring six characters from the start of the string, this index won't help.

Re your comment:
Here's how to do it on MySQL 5.7. That version doesn't support creating an expression index in one step, but you can create a virtual generated column for the expression, and then add an index for that column.
MySQL 5.7 does support the feature that if you use the same expression in a query, it will automatically use the index.
mysql> alter table mytable
    -> add column submycolumn varchar(4) as (substring(mycolumn, 4, 8)),
    -> add index (submycolumn);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> explain SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE SUBSTRING(mycolumn, 4, 8) = '3344';
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table   | partitions | type | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | NULL       | ref  | submycolumn   | submycolumn | 19      | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+


Thanks for the answer. I am using 5.7 so does it support index on substring ?

@Qiulang no, I don't think v5.7 directly supports such indexes. But you can create a generated column with the same expression and index that one. Same restriction applies as with index on an expression.
